# Hitomezashi Stitch patterns with Processing programming

Tags: math, processing

I watched this great video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbfhzlMk2eY&ab_channel=Numberphile from Numberphile and wanted to recreate it using Processing.

The concept is this: Creating random patterns with 2 arrays of binary numbers, first set could be the vowels and consonants in a sentence next one could be even and uneven numbers in a long number like phi.

How do I iterate through my array and then draw the lines with or without an initial offset based on the outcome of the number, first vertical then horizontal or the other way?

I got some of it down, but why does my code not draw all the vertical lines? Does anyone have a take on this fun little problem?

```
fill(0);

int y = 0;
int x = 0;


size(500, 500);
background(102);
noStroke();

int name[] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0};

int pi[]   = {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,3,2,3};
IntList  oddEven;
oddEven = new IntList();


for (int i = 0; i < pi.length; i++) {
     if (pi[i] % 2 == 0) {
         oddEven.append(0); 
         }
         else {
            oddEven.append(1);
         }
          
}


for(int g = 0; g < 17; g++) {

  for(int l = 0; l < 17; l++) {
        
        rect(x, y, 25, 1); 
        x+=50;

  }
  if (oddEven.get(g) % 2 == 0)
  {
   x=25;
   y+=25;
  }
  else{
    x= 0;
    y+=25;
  }
}  
  





for(int xxx = 0; xxx < 14; xxx++) {

  for(int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
          
        rect(x, y, 1, 25); 
        y+=50;

  }
  if (oddEven.get(xxx) % 2 == 0)
  {
   x=25;
   y+=25;
  }
  else{
    y= 0;
    x+=25;
  }
}  


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbfhzlMk2eY&ab_channel=Numberphile
```

Comment: In your second loop I think you’re incrementing y when you mean to increment x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added setup() and draw() and revised the second loop which draws the vertical lines.

```
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
IntList  oddEven;
int name[] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
int pi[]   = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 3};

void setup() {
  size(850, 425);
  background(102);
  //noStroke();
  fill(0);
  oddEven = new IntList();

  for (int i = 0; i < pi.length; i++) {
    if (pi[i] % 2 == 0) {
      oddEven.append(0);
    } else {
      oddEven.append(1);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  // Horizontal lines
  for (int m = 0; m < name.length; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < name.length; n++) {
      rect(x, y, 25, 1); 
      x+=50;
    }
    if (oddEven.get(m) % 2 == 0) {
      x=25;
      y+=25;
    } else {
      x= 0;
      y+=25;
    }
  }  

  // Vertical lines
  for (int a = 0; a < 34; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
      rect(x, y, 1, 25); 
      y+=50;
    }
    x+=25;
    y= 0;
  }
}
```

Revised version which does away with the IntList and uses two arrays of ones and zeroes instead.  Also an odd/even check of the second array is used for the vertical lines. The demo was modified to use lines instead of rectangles for the stitches; therefore, two line grids were used, one for the horizontal stitches and one for the vertical stitches. XOffset is the distance that the first horizontal stitch in each row is offset and yOffset is the distance that the first vertical stitch in each column is offset; both are set based on respective array values.  Note that the vertical stitch array (cols) is twice the size of the horizontal stitch array (rows) since there are two ends to each horizontal stitch.  Conversely, the number of vertical stitches in each column is one half the number of rows since each vertical stitch connects two horizontal stitches and there is a skip between each two rows connected.

```
final int _horzRows = 17;
final int _horzCols = 17;
final int _vertRows = 8;
final int _vertCols = 34;

int rows[] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
int cols[] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;

void horzGrid(int l, int t, int stitchLength) {
  for (int j = 0; j < _horzCols; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < _horzRows; k++) {
      x = l + j*(stitchLength*2); // stitch + skip
      y = t + k*(stitchLength);
      if (rows[k] == 1) {
        xOffset = stitchLength;
      } else {
        xOffset = 0;
      }
      line(x+xOffset, y, x+xOffset + stitchLength, y);
    }
  }
}

void vertGrid(int l, int t, int stitchLength) {
  for (int m = 0; m < _vertCols; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < _vertRows; n++) {
      x = l + m*(stitchLength);
      y = t + n*(stitchLength*2); // stitch + skip
      if (cols[m] == 1) {
        yOffset = stitchLength;
      } else {
        yOffset = 0;
      }
      line(x, y+yOffset, x, y+yOffset + stitchLength);
    }
  }
}

void setup() { 
  size(920, 480);
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  horzGrid(30, 40, 25);
  vertGrid(30, 40, 25);
}

void draw() {
}
```

Comment: Very nice but what if you wanted the same mechanism as with the horizontal lines, where it checks the Array for 0 or 1 and offsets the start of the rect() coordinate accordingly?

Comment: See revision above.

Comment: On the vertical lines , weirdly enough, the code never hits the first part of the if statement.

Comment: I agree, which is probably why I left this out in the first version.  I think the code needs to be rewritten.  I looked at the video again and all that the arrays do is set the position of the first horizontal or vertical stitch in each row or col.  Furthermore, the array for the vertical stitches needs to be twice the size of the  horizontal array; each horizontal stitch has two ends.  The demos so far have used equal sized arrays and that needs to be changed.

Comment: See second revision above.

Comment: very beautifull! Happy Christimas to you!

Comment: Thank you for posting and making us aware of this technique.  There is likely much more that can be done with the source code.  If you found it helpful and answers your question could you please check it as being the answer.

Comment: I will continue to develop the code, adding colours aswell as trying out with the triangle shape.

Comment: I revised it one more time by changing from rectangle stitches to line stitches.  Resulting output is now cleaner with less fudging to line up the two grids.